# jQuery-maskMoney not working with Rails 6

Tags: javascript, jquery, yarnpkg, ruby-on-rails-6

I tried a lot to fix this issue but didn't get any success.
Here package details https://classic.yarnpkg.com/en/package/jquery-maskmoney
I am using

```
rails 6.0.3.1
ruby 2.6.2
```

I followed the below steps.
`$ yarn add jquery-maskmoney`
after this package added successfully into `yarn.lock` and `package.json`

yarn.lock
[image: Screenshot from 2020-08-21 13-12-03]

`package.json`

[image: Screenshot from 2020-08-21 13-12-15]

Now require `jquery-maskmoney` in application.js `app/javascript/packs/application.js`
`require("jquery-maskmoney")`

Getting below error
[image: Screenshot from 2020-08-21 13-19-12]

Can you please help me to fix this issue?
If you need more information please let me know.
Thank you so much in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have implemented solution and it's working fine.

Please download `maskMoney.js` from here [maskMoney.js](https://gist.github.com/sonu1989/2840c5883f0561cabc4dfe956c9b3cb5)

Now follow the steps.

Add the above `jquery-maskmoney.js` in the `app/javascript/packs/modules/common/jquery-maskmoney.js`

In `app/javascript/packs/application.js` import

`import './modules/common/jquery-maskmoney.js'`

Now you use `$('.maskmoney').maskMoney()` in all places.